# Error in CoreData method after adding Google Analytics to project

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, google-analytics, swift2

I have an app with `CoreData`. Everything was working fine until I added `Google Analytics` to the app today using the instructions outlined in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift).

I'm now seeing an error in the `CoreData` methods in the `AppDelegate`:

[image]

The error is:

```
'ErrorType' is not convertible to 'NSError'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
```

I've tried changing it to `as!` and even removing `as NSError` with no luck.

Anyone know what's going on?

**Update:**

I found the culprit but still haven't figured out why it's crashing. When setting up your project with Google Analytics, the guide asks you to add the following code to a viewWillAppear method in each of your view controllers:

```
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "name_of_controller")

    let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

The last line `tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])` causes the build to fail with the error shown above.

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I am able to change the error to a warning if I add an "!" after the "as" (in the highlighted line in the picture above) but I can't fix the problem. It's either an error if I leave the code as is, or a warning if I change it by adding the "!". It doesn't seem right to have to change the standard Core Data stack code. Is there a reliable solution yet? Can the Google Analytics code be changed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

example

```
catch var error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. I tried that but it didn't work. I'm a bit confused because this is the "standard" code that's added to a project when you enable CoreData. For example, I created a test project with CoreData enabled and it had this exact same code without any issues.

Would you mind explaining your code?

Comment: well its standart code for coredata like you said but the catch in your code isnt passing any error variable so he dont recognize the error var you trying to case if after you fixed your code its crash pls post the new crash